# Count non zero vectors in numpy nd array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a ndarray with shape (x,y,d).
How can I get the number of d dimensional non zero vectors (out of the x*y total d dimensional vectors)?

I tried `np.count_nonzero` but I don't think it has the option to do what I described.

Comment: Please provide an example and elaborate on a *nonzero vector*?

Answer (score 0):

actually I think that works:

```
sum(np.any(x) for x in p)
```

(p is the ndarray)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply np.count_nonzeo to the last axis(d). It will return a x * y array with the count of non zero elements in the d dimension. If the count is 0 then it is a zero array, so you just need to count the number of elements in the x * y array which are not equal to 0.

```
np.sum(np.apply_along_axis(np.count_nonzero, 2, your_arr) != 0)
```

Comment: Would you please explain your code, as code-only answers aren't that useful?

Comment: Ok. Added an explanation